# Max height to avoid vertical scrollbar on notebook resolutions

Tags: browsers

So, the most popular notebook resolution is 1366x768.

The viewport height (the height that is available for the web-site in the browser) depends on the operating system and the browser. For instance, the task-bar of Windows 7 is larger then the one on Windows XP. Also, the "header" of IE6 is larger then the one of Chrome.

What would be the available viewport height in the worst case scenario? (Maximized browser window on 1366x768)?

(For Chrome @ Win7 it's 667px.)

**Update:** I know I should have mentioned those toolbars `:)`. Let me clarify: In real life users have either no additional toolbars at all, or they have one or possibly two additional toolbars at max.

I will calculate those toolbars in later. For this question I'd like to know the worst case scenario **with no additional toolbars** present inside the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be better off determining via javascript the resolution of the screen and applying heights based on that, or for a no javascript & no vertical scrollbar use percentages on your layouts.

Trying to code for a specific resolution seems like a much more difficult task than either of the above.

btw, **Worst Case Scenario** (but @Itai beat me too it)...

[image]

looks to be about **150px** :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have heard of toolbars, then you probably know the [worst case scenario is very few pixels](http://common.ziffdavisinternet.com/util_get_image/9/0,1425,sz=1&i=96670,00.jpg), if any. I would find something reasonable that you are happy with in terms of design. People can also stretch the Windows task bar to pretty much whatever height they like.